# Sitecore EXM insert Custom tokens issue

Tags: xconnect, exm

I am using Sitecore 9.0.1 and I am trying to insert custom tokens to email in EXM. I followed Sitecore's documentation and spent hours investigating possible solutions but somehow my tokens did not get filled.

Here are the steps that I took:

1. Created Facet,
2. Created Model for facet and then deployed model (JSON to xConnect, this should work for xconnect side),
3. Added new fields to /sitecore/client/Applications/List Manager/Dialogs/ImportWizardDialog/PageSettings/TabControl Parameters/Map/ImportModel named them FacetName_FieldName,
4. Created FacetMapper and PropertyTokenMap and configured them.

I checked multiple times for possible configuration error, but I can't get tokens to fill.

Can someone help me debug this?

Here is the code reference :

Facet:

```
 namespace Sitecore.Feature.EmailConfiguration.Facets{
[Serializable]
[FacetKey(DefaultFacetKey)]
public class EmailUser:Sitecore.XConnect.Facet
{
    public const string DefaultFacetKey = "EmailUser";
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public EmailUser()
    {

    }
}
}
```

Model:

```
namespace Sitecore.Feature.EmailConfiguration.Models
    {
    public  class EmailUserModel
    {
        public static XdbModel Model { get; } = EmailUserModel.BuildModel();

        public static XdbModel BuildModel()
        {
            XdbModelBuilder modelBuilder = new XdbModelBuilder("EmailUserModel", new XdbModelVersion(0, 1));

            modelBuilder.ReferenceModel(Sitecore.XConnect.Collection.Model.CollectionModel.Model);
            modelBuilder.DefineFacet<Contact, EmailUser>(EmailUser.DefaultFacetKey);

            return modelBuilder.BuildModel();
        }
    }
}
```

FacetMapper:

```
namespace Sitecore.Feature.EmailConfiguration.Mappers
{
    public class EmailUserFacetMapper : IFacetMapper
    {
        private readonly PreferredEmailFacetMapper mapper;

        public EmailUserFacetMapper(): this(CollectionModel.FacetKeys.AddressList)
        {
        }
        public EmailUserFacetMapper(string facetName)
        {
            Assert.ArgumentNotNull(facetName, nameof(facetName));

            this.FacetName = facetName;
        }

        public string FacetName { get; }

        public MappingResult Map(string facetKey, Facet facet, ContactMappingInfo mappings, string[] data)
        {
            using (EventLog eventLog = new EventLog("Application"))
            {
                eventLog.Source = "Application";
                eventLog.WriteEntry("EmailUserFacetMapperCalled facetKey:" +facetKey+" data"+ string.Join("; ", data));
            }

            if (facetKey != this.FacetName)
            {
                return new NoMatch(facetKey);
            }

            var emailUser = new EmailUser();

            var username = mappings.GetValue("EmailUser_Username", data);
            var password = mappings.GetValue("EmailUser_Password",data);

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(username)) { emailUser.Username = username; }
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(password)) { emailUser.Password = password; }

            return (MappingResult)new FacetMapped(facetKey, (Facet) emailUser);
        }
    }
}
```

PropertyTokenMap:

```
namespace Sitecore.Feature.EmailConfiguration.TokenMaps
{
    public class EmailUserPropertyTokenMap : DefaultRecipientPropertyTokenMap
    {
        protected static readonly MethodInfo GetUsernameValue = typeof(FacetExtensions).GetMethod(nameof(FacetExtensions.GetUsernameValue), new[] { typeof(EmailUser) });
        protected static readonly MethodInfo GetPasswordValue = typeof(FacetExtensions).GetMethod(nameof(FacetExtensions.GetPasswordValue), new[] { typeof(EmailUser) });




        static EmailUserPropertyTokenMap()
        {
            if (TokenBindings == null)
            {
                TokenBindings = new Dictionary<Token, RecipientPropertyTokenBinding>();
            }
            RecipientPropertyTokenBinding usernameTokenBinding = RecipientPropertyTokenBinding.Build<EmailUser>(new Token("username"), null, GetUsernameValue);
            RecipientPropertyTokenBinding passwordTokenBinding = RecipientPropertyTokenBinding.Build<EmailUser>(new Token("password"), null, GetPasswordValue);

            TokenBindings.Add(usernameTokenBinding.Token, usernameTokenBinding);
            TokenBindings.Add(passwordTokenBinding.Token, passwordTokenBinding);
        }
    }
    public static class FacetExtensions
    {
        public static string GetUsernameValue(this EmailUser facet)
        {
            return facet.Username;
        }

        public static string GetPasswordValue(this EmailUser facet)
        {
            return facet.Password;
        }
    }
}
```

Xml config:

```
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/" xmlns:set="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/set">
  <sitecore>
    <exm>
      <dispatchTask type="Sitecore.Feature.EmailConfiguration.DispatchTasks.EmailUserDispatchTask, Sitecore.Feature.EmailConfiguration" patch:instead="*[@type='Sitecore.EmailCampaign.Cm.Dispatch.DispatchTask, Sitecore.EmailCampaign.Cm']">
        <param ref="exm/dispatchFailedTaskPool"/>
        <param desc="recipientValidator" ref="exm/recipientValidator" />
        <param desc="contactService" ref="exm/contactService" />
        <param desc="dataProvider" ref="exm/dataProvider" />
        <param desc="itemUtil" ref="exm/itemUtil" />
        <param desc="eventDataService" ref="exm/eventDataService" />
        <param desc="dispatchManager" ref="exm/dispatchManager" />
        <param desc="emailAddressHistoryManager" ref="exm/emailAddressHistoryManager" />
        <param desc="recipientManagerFactory" ref="exm/recipientManagerFactory" />
        <param desc="sentHistoryManager" ref="exm/sentHistoryManager" />
      </dispatchTask>
    </exm>
    <recipients>
      <recipientPropertyTokenMap type="Sitecore.Feature.EmailConfiguration.TokenMaps.EmailUserPropertyTokenMap, Sitecore.Feature.EmailConfiguration" singleInstance="true" patch:instead="*[@type='Sitecore.Modules.EmailCampaign.Core.Personalization.DefaultRecipientPropertyTokenMap, Sitecore.EmailCampaign']" />
    </recipients>

    <import>
      <facetMappers hint="list:Add">
      <facetMapper type="Sitecore.Feature.EmailConfiguration.Mappers.EmailUserFacetMapper,Sitecore.Feature.EmailConfiguration" />
        </facetMappers>
    </import>
    <settings>
      <setting name="ListManagement.Import.FacetsToMap">
        <set:attribute name="value">Emails|Personal|Addresses|EmailUser</set:attribute>
      </setting>
    </settings>

 <xconnect>
      <runtime type="Sitecore.XConnect.Client.Configuration.RuntimeModelConfiguration,Sitecore.XConnect.Client.Configuration">
        <schemas hint="list:AddModelConfiguration">
              <schema name="EmailUserModel" type="Sitecore.XConnect.Client.Configuration.StaticModelConfiguration,Sitecore.XConnect.Client.Configuration">
                  <param desc="modeltype">Sitecore.Feature.EmailConfiguration.Models.EmailUserModel,Sitecore.Feature.EmailConfiguration</param>
              </schema>
        </schemas>
      </runtime>
    </xconnect>

  </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

[image: Core database import wizard map]

Update:
I forgot to put Dispatch task, also i tried debuging this and it loads only 4 other facets without my facet. My test case is load csv i list Manager and then i send test tokens including default and my tokens. Default tokens work but my tokens are empty.

DispatchTask:

```
    namespace Sitecore.Feature.EmailConfiguration.DispatchTasks
{
    public class EmailUserDispatchTask :DispatchTask
    {
        private IContactService _contactService;
        public EmailUserDispatchTask(ShortRunningTaskPool taskPool, IRecipientValidator recipientValidator, IContactService contactService, EcmDataProvider dataProvider, ItemUtilExt itemUtil, IEventDataService eventDataService, IDispatchManager dispatchManager, EmailAddressHistoryManager emailAddressHistoryManager, IRecipientManagerFactory recipientManagerFactory, SentMessageManager sentMessageManager)
        : base(taskPool, recipientValidator, contactService, dataProvider, itemUtil, eventDataService, dispatchManager, emailAddressHistoryManager, recipientManagerFactory, sentMessageManager)
        {
            _contactService = contactService;
        }
        protected override IReadOnlyCollection<IEntityLookupResult<Contact>> GetContacts(List<DispatchQueueItem> dispatchQueueItems)
        {
            var test= _contactService.GetContacts(dispatchQueueItems.Select(x => x.ContactIdentifier), PersonalInformation.DefaultFacetKey, EmailAddressList.DefaultFacetKey, ConsentInformation.DefaultFacetKey, PhoneNumberList.DefaultFacetKey, ListSubscriptions.DefaultFacetKey, EmailAddressHistory.DefaultFacetKey, EmailUser.DefaultFacetKey);
            return test;
        }
    }

}
```

Here is my Json generated for adding model to xconnect to locations 
xconnect_root/App_data/Models and xconnect_root\App_data\jobs\continuous\IndexWorker\App_data\Models

```
{
  "Name": "EmailUserModel",
  "Version": "0.1",
  "References": [
    {
      "Name": "XConnect",
      "Version": "1.0"
    },
    {
      "Name": "Sitecore.XConnect.Collection.Model",
      "Version": "9.0"
    }
  ],
  "Types": {
    "Sitecore.Feature.EmailConfiguration.Facets.EmailUser": {
      "Type": "Facet",
      "BaseType": "Sitecore.XConnect.Facet",
      "ClrType": "Sitecore.Feature.EmailConfiguration.Facets.EmailUser, Sitecore.Feature.EmailConfiguration, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null",
      "Properties": {
        "Username": {
          "Type": "String"
        },
        "Password": {
          "Type": "String"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "Facets": [
    {
      "Target": "Contact",
      "Name": "EmailUser",
      "Type": "Sitecore.Feature.EmailConfiguration.Facets.EmailUser"
    }
  ]
}
```

Update 2: Seems that my Model does not get registered for some reason. I found information that if facet is registered than it will appear in database {siteprefix}_Xdb.Collection.Shard0].[xdb_collection].[ContactFacets] . Is there working example somewhere of adding model to xconnect?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is most likely with your "EmailUserDispatchTask".

You'll need to specify your facet key in the override of the GetContacts method i.e.

```
protected override IReadOnlyCollection<IEntityLookupResult<Contact>> GetContacts(List<DispatchQueueItem> dispatchQueueItems)
{
    return _contactService.GetContacts(dispatchQueueItems.Select(x => x.ContactIdentifier), PersonalInformation.DefaultFacetKey, EmailAddressList.DefaultFacetKey, ConsentInformation.DefaultFacetKey, PhoneNumberList.DefaultFacetKey, ListSubscriptions.DefaultFacetKey, EmailAddressHistory.DefaultFacetKey, ExmKeyBehaviorCache.DefaultFacetKey, EmailUser.DefaultFacetKey);
}
```

Your custom code is otherwise correct, and works just fine on my end.

It may be that your facet is not imported correctly. You can try to manually create a contact in order to verify. First, create an empty contact list in List Manager and copy its id, then programatically create a contact e.g.

```
using (IXdbContext client = SitecoreXConnectClientConfiguration.GetClient())
{
    var contact = new Sitecore.XConnect.Contact(new ContactIdentifier("ListManager", "someemail@domain.com", ContactIdentifierType.Known));

    client.AddContact(contact);

    client.SetEmails(contact, new EmailAddressList(new EmailAddress("someemail@domain.com", false), "Preferred"));

                client.SetListSubscriptions(contact, new ListSubscriptions()
                {
                    Subscriptions = new List<ContactListSubscription>()
                    {
                        new ContactListSubscription(DateTime.UtcNow, true, listId)
                    }
                });

    client.SetEmailUser(contact, new EmailUser()
                {
                    Password = "password",
                    Username = "username"
                });

    client.SetPersonal(contact, new PersonalInformation
                {
                    FirstName = "first name",
                    LastName = "last name"
                });

    client.Submit();
}
```

Where SetEmailUser looks like:

```
public static SetFacetOperation<EmailUser> SetEmailUser(this IXdbContext context, IEntityReference<Contact> contact, EmailUser facet)
{
    return context.SetFacet(new FacetReference(contact, Facets.EmailUser.DefaultFacetKey), facet);
}
```

Comment: Thx for the answer i think i implemented it correct, but _contactService.GetContacts returns only other 4 facets not my facet. I added my DispatchTask code

Comment: @SenadM. See the update to the answer. Also, try to browse to http://<instance-name>/sitecore/admin/showconfig.aspx and ensure that your configuration is patched correctly

Comment: i made console application and tested it using your code and i get error "The type of this instance does not correspond to any type in the model" , seems that my model is not loaded from json, i created json from EmailUserModel and copied to App_Data/models and App_data/jobs/.../App_data/Models in root of xconnect. As for configuration facetmappers tag is repeated again idk if this is ok. It adds my facetmapper to list and then i get another one in web.config below like this http://prntscr.com/kk5tws everything else looks ok including model declaration in xconnect runtime.

Comment: i've added Json for model in post, did you use my xml config on your end?

Comment: I've fixed issue with facetmappers appearing 2x in config i forgot to place it in facetmapper element, but this didnt fix the issue.

Comment: In meantime i figured that i didn't make configuration xml file in in c:\path\to\xconnect\App_data\jobs\continuous\AutomationEngine\AppData\config\sitecore and copied .dll to c:\path\to\xconnect\App_data\jobs\continuous\AutomationEngine but still it does not work.

Comment: Tried adding another facet with model, still nothing updated question, does anyone have working example step by step.

Comment: @SenadM.Best I can suggest is that you verify that you followed all steps on https://doc.sitecore.net/developers/xp/xconnect/xconnect-model/managing-model/deployment.html

Comment: Thank you for help, problem in model deploy was my understanding of "Create a configuration file named sc.Sample.CustomModel.xml" i tought that this was xml config file, but it was xml.config . Also, there is error in FacetMapper where i'm inserting wrong FacetName in constructor, and that's why my Dispatch task wasn't returning Facet .