# Custom EXM DispatchTask is never executed

Tags: exm

I've been following the instructions on [how to create custom personalization tokens](https://doc.sitecore.net/email_experience_manager/configuring_the_delivery_process/recipients/create_a_custom_personalization_token). After following the instructions everything compiles, and everything seemingly works just fine. I can create a new campaign in EXM and I can send a test mail from "Review". However, the test mail doesn't replace my custom tokens.

Having googled a bit I found [this question](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/13409/sitecore-exm-insert-custom-tokens-issue), which is similar, but not identical. The answer to that question was that the custom facets had not been added to the custom `DispatchTask`.

My custom facets, however, *have* been added to my custom `DispatchTask`, and I  know that there's nothing wrong with them as I can read and write to them in XConnect and through `Tracker.Current.Contact`.

It seems that my `CustomDispatchTask` class is never executed, which explains why my custom tokens are not replaced.

`/sitecore/admin/showconfig.aspx` shows that my custom class has indeed been patched in:

```
<exm>
    <dispatchTask
        type="My.Namespace.CustomTokensDispatchTask, MyAssemblyName"
        patch:source="My.EXM.config">
    .....
    </dispatchTask>
</emx>
```

But if I try to debug either the constructor or the overridden `GetContacts` methods, the breakpoints are never hit. I also added some logging to it (in case this code is executed on AppStart where I won't be able to debug fast enough) but those log messages never appear in the log file. There are actually no exceptions or errors in the log files at all.

Why isn't my `CustomTokensDispatchTask` executed?

**CustomTokensDispatchTask.cs**

```
public class CustomTokensDispatchTask : DispatchTask
{
    private readonly IContactService _contactService;

    public CustomTokensDispatchTask([NotNull] ShortRunningTaskPool taskPool, IRecipientValidator recipientValidator, IContactService contactService, EcmDataProvider dataProvider, ItemUtilExt itemUtil, IEventDataService eventDataService, IDispatchManager dispatchManager, EmailAddressHistoryManager emailAddressHistoryManager, IRecipientManagerFactory recipientManagerFactory, SentMessageManager sentMessageManager)
      : base(taskPool, recipientValidator, contactService, dataProvider, itemUtil, eventDataService, dispatchManager, emailAddressHistoryManager, recipientManagerFactory, sentMessageManager)
    {
        Sitecore.Diagnostics.Log.Info("HELLO CustomTokensDispatchTask", this);
        _contactService = contactService;
    }

    protected override IReadOnlyCollection<IEntityLookupResult<Contact>> GetContacts(List<DispatchQueueItem> dispatchQueueItems)
    {
        Sitecore.Diagnostics.Log.Info("HELLO CustomTokensDispatchTask.GetContacts", this);
        return _contactService.GetContacts(dispatchQueueItems.Select(x => x.ContactIdentifier),
            PersonalInformation.DefaultFacetKey,
            AddressList.DefaultFacetKey,
            EmailAddressList.DefaultFacetKey,
            ConsentInformation.DefaultFacetKey,
            PhoneNumberList.DefaultFacetKey,
            ListSubscriptions.DefaultFacetKey,
            MyCustomFacet.DefaultFacetKey);
    }
}
```

**My.EXM.Config**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/" xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform" xmlns:set="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/set">
    <sitecore>
        <exm>
            <dispatchTask set:type="My.Namespace.CustomTokensDispatchTask, MyAssemblyName">
            </dispatchTask>
        </exm>
        <recipients>
            <recipientPropertyTokenMap set:type="My.Namespace.CustomTokensTokenMap, MyAssemblyName">
            </recipientPropertyTokenMap>
        </recipients>
    </sitecore> 
</configuration>
```

Sitecore 9.0.2

Comment: Can you please update your question @GTHvidsten with content of My.EXM.config? Could be that the problem is with patching. I just want to clarify that.

Comment: Added My.EXM.Config now. As you can see by the excerpt from `showconfig.aspx` this is indeed patched in correctly.

Comment: Yes. As I mentioned using the custom facets in XConnect and through `Tracker.Current.Contact` works just fine

Comment: You aren't in emulation mode right? https://doc.sitecore.net/email_experience_manager/configuring_the_delivery_process/performance/testing_exm_performance_in_emulation_mode

Comment: I have read your question once again. You mentioned there that you are sending test mail. Are you using "Send quick test" functionality for this? https://doc.sitecore.net/email_experience_manager/creating_and_editing_messages/testing_messages/send_a_quick_test_of_a_message .

Comment: @PeterProchazka I'm not in emulation mode, and I'm using the "Send quick test" functionality.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you are using "Send quick test" functionality, EXM won't hit your dispatch task.

For "Send quick test" functionality DispatchNewsletter pipeline is using SendTestMessage and therefore TestMessageTask is called instead of your custom DispatchTask.

You need to send email campaign only to your "test" contact to hit your custom Dispatch Task

Comment: If this is the case, how can you make sure that your custom tokens are replaced properly without having to actually send the campaing (or creating a campaign with one user, as suggested, and then having to copy settings from one campaign to the other, or having to reset engagement plans)? (It seems a bit silly to not be able to test custom tokens)

Comment: You can use "Preview for recipients" button under Message tab where you edit content of message. Take a look here -> https://doc.sitecore.net/email_experience_manager/creating_and_editing_messages/editing_messages/insert_a_token_in_a_message section "Preview the token for different recipients"

Comment: "Preview for recipients" still doesn't replace my custom tokens with the actual values.

Comment: And when you send email campaign? Are you hitting your code?

Comment: I have to draw back my previous statement. Obviously "Preview for recipients"  won't call your custom Dispatch Task :) I was too quick with writing it down. But still tokens should be replaced with preview...

Comment: I did a full send of the campaign, and then my log messages from `CustomTokensDispatchTask` appeared in the log file. The custom tokens were still not replaced, though.

Comment: As your custom dispatch task was triggered, this question is answered I think. For tokens not replaced, I would suggest creating new question where you will put also code from your CustomTokensTokenMap class.

Comment: I think I've come to terms with this limitation now, and just hope Sitecore does something about it in the future. In the mean time, do you know if it's possible to extend `TestMessageTask` to ensure the functionality will work in "preview" as well? I searched all the config files but couldn't find any reference to it, so I suspect it's not possible, but would be great with a second opinion :)

Comment: When I was looking today quickly, it is somehow possible as far as I can saw in original assembly but you would need to override lot of classes in Sitecore.EmailCampaign.Cm.dll. I am not next to computer right now so cannot check in more detail...

Comment: I suggest to contact Sitecore Support and describe this situation. As this feature is there from what I assume beginning of this module, would be tough to change behaviour. It kind of also makes sense it is implemented that way but unfortunately it is not documented therefore really confusing for first time users as you would assume it worked similarly as sending campaign normally... Maybe Sitecore Support can find some "workaround" for you...